# I keep losing my ability to run programs with normal left click...must right click and run as administrator

Tags: windows-7

When I do the normal left click on any icon, I get the message This file does not have a program associated with it for performing this action. Please install a program or, if one is already installed, create an association in the Default Programs control panel. I've found that I can use the right click and use "Run as Administrator" and it will work. That's what makes me suspect a change in the UAC. I am running Win7 on an older PC...2003. 
DELL Inspiron E1705.

This has happened on numerous occasions.  I'm the only user on this PC. I am the administrator. I have not changed anything in the UAC.  I do have ToolWiz which oversees everything on the PC. Can it be changing things that could cause this?  It even accesses the Registry. I also have Driver Update that in installed when changing from WinXP to Win7 because I had problems. 
What can I do to resolve this.  I've tried to restore but it didn't resolve it this time.

Too, I am not a PC guru so a lot of what I've read here is a little above my head.  I know enough about PC's to be able to REALLY get into trouble.

Dusti

Comment: If you right click a file, choose open with->choose program, and then select the program from the list, and check "always open using this program" does that fix it? I ask this instead of giving this as a solution because it might not fix the issue. In the registry there's a place where file ascociation takes place. In windows 7 it is a bit more complicated than in earlier windows versions and it may get screwed up there that requires a lot of manual actions. Before giving that solution I want to test this first.

Comment: Hi Chip, Thanks for the response.  You are using the term file and I'm not having a problem with opening a file. I can't run programs like Firefox, Malware Anti Malware, ITunes, etc.  If I right click on these I'm not given the option to choose what program to use.

Comment: Ah, you said: when I click on any Icon. That sounded to me like files.

Comment: What did you do last time to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you can't start any program it is possible some malware has changed the following in your registry.

1. Start regedit by going to start and type regedit in the searchbar, then press enter.
2. Navigate to the following key: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell
3. if it has a subkey called Command, delete it. It should only have removeproperties folder.